# Navigating JSON in Python?

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine

**ANSWER:** The square brackets inside data["data"]["items"] indicates a list of dictionaries. I had thought that the brackets indicated that all of those dictionaries were a list *inside* a list of one item (i.e. [[item1, item2]]) so I had to call a 0 index like so: data["data"]["items"][0]. That was incorrect, the [0] is unecessary, which I really should have known, but didn't realize.

---

I am using GAE, so you can think of the `self.response.write` statement as a `print`.

For some reason, although the user_xid prints correctly, the interpreter is giving me the error when I try to parse `json_data["data"]["items"][0]` in my `for` loop, it appears to be evaluating `x` as a `string`, because I am getting an error telling me that string indicies must be integers.

I didn't realize `json_data["data"]["items"][0]` would yield a string. I'm somewhat stymied. Would it have anything to do with using `json_data["data"]["items"][0]` as opposed to `json_data["data"]["items"]`?

I have also tried `json.loads(json_data["data"]["items"][0])` to no avail. Any input is appreciated.

I have the following JSON, which I have broken out a bit to make it easier to read:

```
 {"meta":
    {"user_xid": "REDACTED", "message": "OK", "code": 200, "time": 1436273692},
"data":
    {"items": [

        {"time_completed": 1436193938, "xid": "4tLz2M3x8_E9mTPIQsQUdrj-83spikha", "title": "for 7h 40m", "time_created": 1436165067, "time_updated": 1436194828, "details":

            {"body": 0, "sound": 14348, "tz": "America/Vancouver", "awakenings": 1, "light": 13258, "mind": 0, "asleep_time": 1436165760, "awake": 1265, "rem": 0, "duration": 28871, "smart_alarm_fire": 1436193000, "quality": 81, "awake_time": 1436193600, "sunrise": 1436184840, "sunset": 1436156340},

        "date": 20150706, "shared": true, "sub_type": 0},

        {"time_completed": 1436135400, "xid": "4tLz2M3x8_Hk71lnuSLbeq4ascwJg-J8", "title": "for 25m", "time_created": 1436133600, "time_updated": 1436135590, "details":

             {"body": 0, "sound": 0, "tz": "America/Vancouver", "awakenings": 0, "light": 1500, "mind": 0, "asleep_time": 1436133600, "awake": 300, "rem": 0, "duration": 1800, "smart_alarm_fire": 0, "quality": 2, "awake_time": 1436134800, "sunrise": 0, "sunset": 0},

             "date": 20150705, "shared": true, "sub_type": 2},

        {"time_completed": 1436133497, "xid": "4tLz2M3x8_GIYf6G9_ZKH9xrKpuEzMjm", "title": "for 23m", "time_created": 1436131387, "time_updated": 1436135461, "details":

            {"body": 0, "sound": 1391, "tz": "America/Vancouver", "awakenings": 0, "light": 0, "mind": 0, "asleep_time": 1436132100, "awake": 719, "rem": 0, "duration": 2110, "smart_alarm_fire": 1436133445, "quality": 4, "awake_time": 1436133300, "sunrise": 0, "sunset": 0},

        "date": 20150705, "shared": true, "sub_type": 1},

        {"time_completed": 1436117080, "xid": "4tLz2M3x8_EUZyqCoXYOJO7Hfe92eSqg", "title": "for 26m","time_created": 1436115061, "time_updated": 1436121619, "details":

            {"body": 0, "sound": 480, "tz": "America/Vancouver", "awakenings": 0, "light": 1119, "mind": 0, "asleep_time": 1436115479, "awake": 420, "rem": 0, "duration": 2019, "smart_alarm_fire": 1436117069, "quality": 2, "awake_time": 1436116800, "sunrise": 1436098380, "sunset": 1436156280},

        "date": 20150705, "shared": true, "sub_type": 1}, 

        ],

        "links":
            {"next": "REDACTED"}, 

"size": 10}

}
```

I am using the following in Python:

```
json_data = json.loads(user_data)
        self.response.write('<br><br>x_id: ' + json_data["meta"]["user_xid"])
        i = 0
        for x in json_data["data"]["items"][0]:
            duration = x['details']['duration']
            date = x["date"]
            self.response.write('<br><br>sleep number ' + str(i) + ' | duration: ' + str(duration) + ' | date: ' + str(date))
            i += 1
```

I am using GAE, so you can think of the `self.response.write` statement as a `print`.

For some reason, although the user_xid prints correctly, the interpreter is giving me the error when I try to parse `json_data["data"]["items"][0]` in my `for` loop, it appears to be evaluating `x` as a `string`, because I am getting an error telling me that string indicies must be integers.

I didn't realize `json_data["data"]["items"][0]` would yield a string. I'm somewhat stymied. Would it have anything to do with using `json_data["data"]["items"][0]` as opposed to `json_data["data"]["items"]`?

I have also tried `json.loads(json_data["data"]["items"][0])` to no avail. Any input is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why is this getting voted down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing some basic debugging and data examination you will find that the use of the [0] is incorrect

I quickly loaded that data and tried it

```
In [11]: for i in x['data']['items'][0]:
....:     print i
....:     
time_completed
xid
details
title
date
shared
sub_type
time_created
time_updated
```

And this is effectively what you got, but not what you expected.

So what is going on?  If you you do the following

```
x['data']['items'][0]
Out[28]: 
{'date': 20150706,
 'details': {'asleep_time': 1436165760,
  'awake': 1265,
  'awake_time': 1436193600,
  'awakenings': 1,
  'body': 0,
  'duration': 28871,
  'light': 13258,
  'mind': 0,
  'quality': 81,
  'rem': 0,
  'smart_alarm_fire': 1436193000,
  'sound': 14348,
  'sunrise': 1436184840,
  'sunset': 1436156340,
  'tz': 'America/Vancouver'},
 'shared': True,
 'sub_type': 0,
 'time_completed': 1436193938,
 'time_created': 1436165067,
 'time_updated': 1436194828,
 'title': 'for 7h 40m',
 'xid': '4tLz2M3x8_E9mTPIQsQUdrj-83spikha'}
```

The result is as you expect.

The answer is because you are trying to iterate over `x['data']['items'][0]`

When you iterate over a dictionary you will get the keys not the values by default. Hence you are getting the unexpected string.

Where as the following code will give you what you want.

```
In [30]: for i in x['data']['items']:
            print i['details']['duration']
   ....:     
   28871
   1800
   2110
   2019
```

This iterates over each item (a dictioanary) in the list of items.

I would suggest the downvote is due to a large posting of code, and no real evidence of basic debugging.

Comment: Thanks! I have been trying to debug this, but I'm a pretty big newby.

Comment: Great, I tried it, and it works. I haven't really used JSON before, and I did try to load it into the interpreter to test out the data, but I couldn't actually figure out how to do that (I'm pretty new at this stuff). json_data["data"]["item"] yields the list of dictionaries where the first key in each of those dictionaries is "time_completed"... the square prackets inside the items key threw me off. Thanks again!

Comment: No probs.  Just realize however the problem isn't json related but how nested dcitionaries and lists work in python.